# IdentityServer4 with a customise ConfigurationDBContext

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext, identityserver4

Is it Okay if I customise the ConfigurationDBContext? I have already created one, the code is below

```
public class MyConfigurationDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext
{    
        public MyConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, 
                ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions)
                : base(options, storeOptions)
        {                
        }
}
```

I noticed that ConfigurationDBContext requires special DbContextOptions

```
DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext>
```

I am bit confused now. Before i go any further just want to check has anybody done this before? Or if anyone can point out to project or tutorial regarding this.

Comment: MJK, any luck with this?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented and add two more entities into that. Most of the times, I just pass the newly initialized object.

Comment: Can I share your answer on how you implemented your custom ConfigurationDbContext? I'm getting this error: No parameterless constructor was found on 'IdentityConfigurationDbContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'IdentityConfigurationDbContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory<IdentityConfigurationDbContext>' in the same assembly as 'IdentityConfigurationDbContext'.

Comment: at what point, you are getting the error? Why don't you ask a question with your code in StackOverflow? if you can add the link here, I can give it a try. cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618235/using-identityserver4-with-custom-configration-dbcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `IConfigurationDbContext` from [IdentityServer4.EntityFramework](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/00024943493657a00703c42863d108701323f448/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Interfaces/IConfigurationDbContext.cs#L10)

```
public interface IConfigurationDbContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    DbSet<IdentityResource> IdentityResources { get; set; }
    DbSet<ApiResource> ApiResources { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This interface is there to allow developers to customize the context. If you donot want to inherit from `ConfigurationDbContext`(bind to `Ef.Core.DbContext`), you can build your own implementation of `IConfigurationDbContext` just need to add `IDbContextFactory<MyConfigurationDbContext>`

```
public class IdentityConfigurationDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyConfigurationDbContext>
{
    public MyConfigurationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```